# Switch between column while searching

Tags: excel, vba

I'm using this code in my program to search in excel sheet, but in the column A1 only, if I want to add command or function to help changing between columns A1,B1,C1,..., thank you in advance.

```
Private Sub cmdsearch_Click()
    blnNew = False
        txtChem1.Text = ""
        txtChem2.Text = ""
        txtChem3.Text = ""
TRows = Worksheets("Data").Range("A1").CurrentRegion.Rows.Count            
    For i = 2 To TRows
        If Val(Trim(ComboBox1.Text)) = Val(Trim(Worksheets("Data").Cells(i, 1).Value)) Then    
        txtChem1.Text = Worksheets("Data").Cells(i, 1).Value
        txtChem2.Text = Worksheets("Data").Cells(i, 2).Value
        txtChem3.Text = Worksheets("Data").Cells(i, 3).Value  
        Exit For
        End If    
    Next i
    If Trim(txtChem1.Text) = "" Then
        cmdSave.Enabled = False
        cmdDelete.Enabled = False
        Frame2.Enabled = False
    Else
        cmdSave.Enabled = True
        cmdDelete.Enabled = True
        Frame2.Enabled = True
    End If
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Hi you can create a function same this:

```
Sub Search(CellParams)
 blnNew = False
        txtChem1.Text = ""
        txtChem2.Text = ""
        txtChem3.Text = ""
TRows = Worksheets("Data").Range(CellParams).CurrentRegion.Rows.Count            
    For i = 2 To TRows
        If Val(Trim(ComboBox1.Text)) = Val(Trim(Worksheets("Data").Cells(i, 1).Value)) Then    
        txtChem1.Text = Worksheets("Data").Cells(i, 1).Value
        txtChem2.Text = Worksheets("Data").Cells(i, 2).Value
        txtChem3.Text = Worksheets("Data").Cells(i, 3).Value  
        Exit For
        End If    
    Next i
    If Trim(txtChem1.Text) = "" Then
        cmdSave.Enabled = False
        cmdDelete.Enabled = False
        Frame2.Enabled = False
    Else
        cmdSave.Enabled = True
        cmdDelete.Enabled = True
        Frame2.Enabled = True
    End If
End Sub
```

And in your button you can use:

```
Private Sub cmdsearch_Click()
   Search("A1")
End Sub
```

Comment: No, this will still search in column A only. Change `Val(Trim(Worksheets("Data").Cells(i, 1).Value))` to `Val(Trim(Worksheets("Data").Cells(i, CellParams.Column).Value))`.

Comment: Hi, thank you guys for your answers, I have tried both, but it does not work, if I want to add to my code a command which allowed me to switch between columns, how can I do it, thank you in advance.